# Gallery view remove focus - Android

Tags: android

I want to remove focus in gallery for a selected item. I am getting an output like this, Here is an image : [image]

Here first item selected. So it is looking darker than 2nd image. I want to display an image as it is not focused or selected.

Please anyone help. I'll really appreciate that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a statelist drawable (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) and customize the "selected" state to whatever you want there,  in your case transparent . Then you provide this drawable as the background for the item.

EDIT:

Also look in to gallery

```
 android:unselectedAlpha
```

Comment: no probs .. :) , which solution was successfull ? drawable or removing unselectedalpha ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like

View.clearFocus()

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
myLayout.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Yes I tried that. But it is not working for Gallery. Give me another option please

Answer (score 0):

try to apply  below two property in your xml to your gallery.

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusable="false"
```